# Check to Determine Which Constructor was Called To Format toString Method

Tags: java, string

I have the following class and two constructors:

```
public Book(String bookTitle,ConcurrentHashMap<Integer,String> authors, String bookType ) throws InvalidDataException{

    this.setBookTitle(bookTitle);
    this.setAuthors(authors);
    this.setType(bookType);

}

public Book(String bookTitle,ConcurrentHashMap<Integer,String> authors, String bookType, String bookStyle, String ISBN, int numberofPages) throws InvalidDataException{
        this (bookTitle,authors,bookType);
    this.fullConstructor = true;
    this.setStyle(bookStyle);
    this.setISBN(ISBN);
    this.setNumberofPages(numberofPages);
}
```

I also have the following variable:

`private Boolean fullConstructor= false;` to check which constructor was called.

I did this so that I can properly format my `toString()` method:

```
@Override
public String toString() {

String viewOutput="";

if (!this.fullConstructor)
{
    viewOutput="Book: " + this.getBookTitle() + " " + " Author(s): " + this.loopAuthors() + " Genre: " + this.bookType;
}
else{
    viewOutput="Book: " + this.getBookTitle() + " " + " Author(s): " + this.loopAuthors() + " Genre: " + this.bookType + " Book Style: " + this.getBookStyle() + " ISBN-10: " + this.getISBN() + " Number of Pages: " + this.getNumberofPages() + " Book Style: " +this.getBookStyle() + " ISBN: " + this.getISBN() + "Number of Pages: " + this.getNumberofPages(); 
}

return viewOutput;
}
```

Explanation:

If the full constructor is called the private variable fullConstructor is set to true. The toString knows how to format the return value based on the fullConstructor value. I did it this way, because I would have to check again to see what variables are empty, which the setters already do, it seemed repetitive.

Is what I did in bad practice? If so, how do I properly check if the values are empty so that I can correctly create the return string?

Comment: Have you considered making a subclass of `Book` which has the style, ISBN and page number fields?

Comment: @resueman - I could, but, what's wrong with the constructors?

Comment: Well it seems like you're trying to have two different kinds of books, and manually keeping track of which is which. If you use inheritance, you can keep the shared behavior, and easily handle the differences. It will basically keep track of the two types for free, instead of having to do it yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd probably use this:

```
public Book(String bookTitle, Map<Integer, String> authors, String bookType, String bookStyle, String isbn, int numberOfPages) throws InvalidDataException {
    setBookTitle(bookTitle);
    setAuthors(authors);
    setType(bookType);
    setStyle(bookStyle);
    setISBN(isbn);
    setNumberOfPages(numberOfPages);
}

public Book(String bookTitle, Map<Integer, String> authors, String bookType) throws InvalidDataException {
    this(bookTitle, authors, bookType, null, null, null);
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    String result = String.format("Book: %s Author(s): %s Genre: %s",
            getBookTitle(), loopAuthors(), bookType);
    if (getBookStyle() == null && getISBN() == null && getNumberOfPages() == null)
        return result;
    return String.format("%s Book Style: %s ISBN-10: %s Number of Pages: %s",
            result, getBookStyle(), getISBN(), getNumberOfPages());
}
```

That way, you don't need a "fully-constructed" flag (seeing as the additional fields have setters and could be called later); the fields are just checked at `toString` time. Also, I took the liberty of changing your `toString` method to use `String.format`, and to be less repetitious.